# Why was the 'Elephants and Dinosaurs' question deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was in the middle of answering the question when (I believe) it was deleted.

(It was a three part logic question about a world of elephants and dinosaurs that always tell the truth about their own species but lie about the other.)

The user who posted it was new to SE and so it was confusing at first (s/he posted an edit as an answer) but was responding to comments and cleaning it up. A little more editing may have helped, but I certainly didn't think it was unsalvageable.

So **why was it deleted, or did the user delete it?** And in either event, **would it be okay for me to repost it with better formatting** so I can post the answer I composed?

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a link to the question in... question.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23787/39) (requires the view deleted posts privilege) It was self-deleted by the original poster.

Instead of reposting it yourself, you could either try to convince the OP to undelete it or get three separate users to vote to undelete it (this requires 4k rep).

Comment: @Josh I checked it out, and it looks like it was cleaned up a bit by Engineer Toast.  I've voted to undelete.  It still doesn't seem like a stellar question, but I think it does fit the site.  We can let votes determine its worth.

Comment: Thanks guys. It can be confusing not having the rep to see what's going on.

Comment: Voted to undelete. Whether it's a *good* puzzle depends (IMO) on whether the questions have unique answers that can be worked out, but it's definitely a puzzle within our definition.

Comment: Voted to undelete. The question is alive again.